# Twitter bootstrap top navbar with easily clickable buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a fixed top navbar. Everything is fine for desktop. But it is hard to click links and buttons in mobile phones.

User can't click green areas:

[image]

Is it possible or easily implementable to make navbar stack and toggle button to be easily clickable. 
For example user can click each of the three sections like this: [image]

My code and fiddle is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/RaArC/11/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top visible-xs" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-part2"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-part3" style="padding: 3px 15px;">
            <img src="http://www.wdc.com/Global/images/icons/icon_supporthelp.gif" width="24" height="24" alt="aaaa">
        </button>
        <div style="padding-top: 15px;"> <a href="/page0" title="aaa" style="color:#ffffff;margin-top:40px;">Example.com</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-part2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/page1">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/page2">page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-part3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/page3">page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/page4">page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

(similar question without answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789280/small-clickable-area-in-navbar-collapse-button-css-bootstrap-v3))

Comment: Where is the result in JSFiddle?

Comment: You can see by clicking JSFiddle link.

Comment: Oh... responsive, sorry... I'm using 1920x1080 resolution. So, I couldn't notice...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Make your divs like this]

Make your divs like this. **width: 10%;** and **width: 80%;**

You can change these percentages as you want. And then with **float: left;** arrange the divs.

Images of divs must be centered. background positions must be **center center**

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/RaArC/14/

I changed the styling of your "Example.com" link to "display:block" and removed the surrounding `<div>` (which was only providing some padding that I incorporated into the link block itself.)

```
<a href="/page0" title="aaa" style="color:#fff;padding:15px 0px;display:block;">Example.com</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make left and right sides as a block, so user can click the area around the right and left buttons ?

Comment: Not without wrapping the buttons in their own `<div>`s and using JavaScript to detect a click and open the menus. That's probably more than you want and I'm not sure it's a good idea -- I think you can probably rely on your users hitting the buttons accurately!  I did update to prevent a click directly adjacent to the buttons from triggering the "Example.com" link, which was a problem.  That's the `margin:0px 90px 0px 70px` property, so you can adjust that boundary to whatever you're comfortable with.  I also added a bit of margin to your left button. :) http://jsfiddle.net/RaArC/16/